# Scrapy: follow pagination links not working

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

**Set-up**

I'm scraping housing ads using the scrapy example given [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns).

In my case, I follow links to housing ad pages in stead of author pages, and subsequently scrap housing ad page for information.

---

**Problem**

My code successfully follows links to housing ad pages and scrapes the information per ad. However, it does so only for the initial page, i.e. it does not follow the pagination links.

---

**Code so far**

```
class RoomsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rooms'

    start_urls = ['https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/london']

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to ad pages
        for href in response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="maincontent"]/ul/li/article/header[1]',
            ).css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                             callback=self.parse_ad)

        # follow pagination links 
        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong/a/@href',
            ).extract()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)      

     def parse_ad(self, response):
     # code extracting ad information follows here, 
     # finalising the code with a yield function.
```

So, I am basically following the example. I do not receive an error regarding the pagination link part when running the code, and the query path is correct (I believe).

Have I placed the `# follow pagination links` part correctly in the code? I'm lost.

Comment: Have you tested `response.xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong/a',).css('a::attr(href)').extract()` in scrapy shell for example? I suspect this does not work because chaining XPath's `...../a` selected elements with CSS `a` descendants will never match (links don't have link children). Try XPath `/*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong/a/@href` or `/*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong` followed by CSS `a::attr(href)` if you really want to use XPath and CSS

Comment: @paultrmbrth, `response.xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/stron‌​g/a',).css('a::attr(‌​href)').extract()` works in Scrapy shell. That is, it provides me with the 'next' href.

Comment: I've changed it to `response.xpath('//[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong/a/@href').extract()` which gives the href. I'll change it in the question.

Comment: @paultrmbrth. I found the issue, the href was returned as a one-element list, not a string. Just changed it into a string and now everything works fine... Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: Right, I was about to say that the example you linked uses `.extract_first()`, not `.extract()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to be a silly mistake:

```
 for href in response.xpath(
        '//*[@id="maincontent"]/ul/li/article/header[1]',
        ).css('a::attr(href)').extract():
```

provides a one-element list containing the pagination href, e.g. `['\href']`. But for the code to work, a string is needed, e.g. `'\href'`. Therefore, in the code snippet above, replace `extract()` with `extract()[0]`.

Comment: The idiomatic way is to use `.extract_first()`. It helps with index errors when there's no match.